# Subdropdown in html

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

How can we show the value selected from subdropdown menu to the top of the dropdown list.Is it possible with javascript.My html code was

If we select any course from any of the subdropdown ,it will show at the top position of dropdown.Is it possible.Please help me.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <p>
    <h5>Departments</h5>
  </p>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin-left:0px;padding-left:0px;">Select
    <span class="caret"></span></button>


  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">MCA</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">B.Tech <span class="caret"></span></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">EEE</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Civil</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Mechanical</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Computer science</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Aeronautics</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">M.Tech <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Courses</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">IC Technology</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Civil</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">DataScience</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Computer science</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Environmental Engineering</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below example.

```js
const dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
const subDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('optgroup');

subDropdowns.forEach((optgroup) => {
    optgroup.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const selectedValue = event.target.value;
        dropdown.value = selectedValue;
        dropdown.insertBefore(dropdown.querySelector(`[value="${selectedValue}"]`), dropdown.firstElementChild);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Selection</title>
    <style>
        /* Your CSS styles here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <select id="dropdown">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
        <optgroup label="B.Tech">
            <option value="Courses">Courses</option>
            <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
            <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
            <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
            <option value="ComputerScience">Computer science</option>
            <option value="Aeronautics">Aeronautics</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="M.Tech">
            <option value="Courses">Courses</option>
            <option value="ICTechnology">IC Technology</option>
            <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
            <option value="DataScience">DataScience</option>
            <option value="ComputerScience">Computer science</option>
            <option value="EnvironmentalEngineering">Environmental Engineering</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please address how this answers the question. Code-only answers are not good answers